# asp.net mvc saving data to database using EF

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a repository class shown as below. My create method is here. I am going to save my data into 3 tables in my SQL Server database.

My tables are `tblSemesterRegistration`, `tblSemesterSubject` and `tblSemesterCampu`.

In here `tblSemesterSubject` and `tblSemesterCampu` has foreign keys from `tblSemesterRegistration`. That foreign key is `SemesterID` which is an auto increment id.

My problem is the `SemesterID` foreign key is not saving to `tblSemesterCampu` or `tblSemesterSubject`. But when I try to save data to only one table it works fine.

Does anyone have an idea about how to solve this problem please. Thanks...

```
public string Create(SemesterRegistationModel model, string SubjectCredit)
{
    tblSemesterRegistration tb = new tblSemesterRegistration();
    tb.AcadamiYear = model.AcadamiYear;                       
    context.tblSemesterRegistrations.Add(tb);
    foreach (string subjectcredit in array)
    {
        string[] arraycredit = subjectcredit.Split(',');
        arraycredit = arraycredit.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();
        int subject1 = Convert.ToInt32(arraycredit[0]);
        tblSemesterSubject tbss = new tblSemesterSubject();
        tbss.SemesterID = tb.SemesterID;
        tbss.Subject = subject1;
        context.tblSemesterSubjects.Add(tbss);
    }

    foreach (CampusSelectModel Campus in model.lst_campus)
    {
        tblSemesterCampu tbcam = new tblSemesterCampu();
        tbcam.SemesterID = tb.SemesterID;
        tbcam.CampusName = Campus.Name;
        context.tblSemesterCampus.Add(tbcam);
    }

    Save();                                                    
    model.SemesterID = tb.SemesterID;
}
```

Comment: Are you using Code First? or Database First? can you post your model code?

Answer (score 0):

When you are adding first table to the context primary key will not generate untill you will not save the context.

So, save the context when adding the first table and then run this code. I thing it will work.

```
tblSemesterRegistration tb = new tblSemesterRegistration();
tb.AcadamiYear = model.AcadamiYear;                       
context.tblSemesterRegistrations.Add(tb);
save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I solved this problem..My tblSemesterCampu foreign key  was a nullable int value. now I change it to not nullable int value. Now it's working properly...